# FreeBSD: Shared object "libarchive.so.6" not found, required by "pkg"

Tags: pi-3, freebsd

I installed FreeBSD into Raspberry pi 3, but after downloading and extracting ports tree from `portsnap`. Now, I also installed `pkg` (ports-management) binary for binary installation. But, after installation of `pkg` i tried lots of others binary installation using `pkg` but it throws an error

`[root@rpi3 /usr/ports/net]# pkg
Shared object "libarchive.so.6" not found, required by "pkg"
[root@rpi3 /usr/ports/net]# uname -a 
FreeBSD rpi3 12.0-CURRENT FreeBSD 12.0-CURRENT #0 r318898M: Thu May 25 15:07:15 MDT 2017     raspberry@hive.raspbsd.org:/usr/home/brd/rpi3/crochet/work/obj/arm64.aarch64/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  arm64
[root@rpi3 /usr/ports/net]#`

**Shared object "libarchive.so.6" not found, required by "pkg"**

I tried updating or reinstalling it using `pkg-static bootstrap -f` but nothing happened. 
I also tried re-installation from ports tree,but again nothing happened.

I also followed this below link , but nothing works.

[Shared object “libarchive.so.5” not found, required by “pkg”](https://serverfault.com/questions/575887/shared-object-libarchive-so-5-not-found-required-by-pkg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue so I added a symlink to libarchive.so to resolve.

## ln -s /usr/lib/libarchive.so /usr/lib/libarchive.so.6

(now mind you I'm in no way a BSD expert so confirm the consequences of this and or best practice)

Comment: Thanks for your help :) . I searched a lot about configuring or installing any binary that will also load   `libarchive.so.7` library file , and i forgot about making  a simple symlink  to `libarchive.so.6` :D

Comment: Confirmed that this worked for me on Rpi 3.

Comment: Confirmed! Worked for me on Rpi3, raspbsd.

Answer (score 1):

Using pkg-static instead of pkg will work around this.

This happens because arm64 packages are built against an older userland where ino64 updates affect some system components.

Comment: Well , right now, issue was solved by above answer by @david and also thanks for your update on this, but i already used pkg-static so many times but nothing worked.